# How to add APP-INF/classes to my EAR with Gradle

Tags: gradle, ear

I am building an ear with Gradle. So far my configuration is very simple:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

ear {
  libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'
}

dependencies {
    deploy project(path: ':MyProjectWeb', configuration: 'archives')

    earlib project(':ModuleA')
    earlib project(':ModuleB')
}
```

I also have `:ModuleC`, whose **classes** I'd like to place into `APP-INF/classes`, rather than copying `ModuleC.jar` into `APP-INF/lib`.

How can I do this with Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be similar to:

```
ear {
  libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'

  from(project(':modc').sourceSets.main.output) {
      into('APP-INF/classes')
  }
}
```

Sample demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/29297782).